# nameof with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, mono, c#-6.0

I was experimenting with `nameof` with generics. I didn't get the result I was expecting. I'm not sure if this is part of the spec or not.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ($"Hello { nameof(FooBar<string>)! }");
    }
}

class FooBar<T> { }
```

The output I get is

> Hello FooBar!

I would expect some details about the type parameters.

I tried it with a method and that fails with a compiler error:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ($"Hello { nameof(Do<string>) }");
    }

    public static T Do<T>() {}
}
```

> Error CS8084: An argument to nameof operator cannot be method group with type arguments (CS8084) (foo)

Is this because `nameof` is a compile-time construct and generics are types initialized at runtime? Or is there some other limitation?

Comment: Related: you may instead need typeof(T).Name or typeof(T).FullName as described in [How do I get the type name of a generic type argument?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2581642)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I would expect some details about the type parameters

From the design docs:

> **Result of nameof.** The result of nameof depends on the symbols that its
>   argument bound to:
>
> One or more members: if all members have the same metadata name then
>   the result of nameof is that name; otherwise it is an error "This
>   argument refers to multiple elements with different names". The
>   metadata name of a member **I`or`I< isA1...AK>` is simply "I" after standard
>   identifier transformations have been applied.**

The `<T>` parameter is removed due to standard identifier transformations (section §2.4.2 in the C# specification) which doesn't permit `<>` as valid identifiers. First any leading @ is removed, then Unicode escape sequences are transformed, and then any formatting characters are removed. This of course still happens at compile-time. You can also see this when you try to print out the name of a generic type:

```
typeof(List<string>).Name;
```

Will result in:

```
List`1
```

> Is this because nameof is a compile-time construct and generics are
>   types initialized at runtime? Or is there some other limitation?

The second error is specified as invalid by design to avoid overload resolution complications inside `nameof`:

> **Allow generic type arguments?** Presumably 'yes' when naming a type
>   since that's how expression binding already works. And **presumably 'no.'
>   when naming a method-group since type arguments are used/inferred
>   during overload resolution, and it would be confusing also to have to
>   deal with that in nameof.**

We can see that clearly in the roslyn codebase:

```
private BoundExpression BindNameofOperatorInternal(InvocationExpressionSyntax node, 
                                                   DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
{
    CheckFeatureAvailability(node.GetLocation(), MessageID.IDS_FeatureNameof, diagnostics);

    var argument = node.ArgumentList.Arguments[0].Expression;
    string name = "";

    // We relax the instance-vs-static requirement for top-level member access expressions by creating a NameofBinder binder.
    var nameofBinder = new NameofBinder(argument, this);
    var boundArgument = nameofBinder.BindExpression(argument, diagnostics);

    if (!boundArgument.HasAnyErrors && CheckSyntaxForNameofArgument(argument, out name, diagnostics) && boundArgument.Kind == BoundKind.MethodGroup)
    {
        var methodGroup = (BoundMethodGroup)boundArgument;
        if (!methodGroup.TypeArgumentsOpt.IsDefaultOrEmpty)
        {
            // method group with type parameters not allowed
            diagnostics.Add(ErrorCode.ERR_NameofMethodGroupWithTypeParameters, argument.Location);
        }
        else
        {
            nameofBinder.EnsureNameofExpressionSymbols(methodGroup, diagnostics);
        }
    }

    return new BoundNameOfOperator(node, boundArgument, ConstantValue.Create(name), Compilation.GetSpecialType(SpecialType.System_String));
}
```

For the full specification, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions