# nameof with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, c#-6.0

I am trying to get the name of a method on a generic interface. I would expect this to work as the type part would be a valid typeof:

```
//This does not compile
nameof(IGenericInterface<>.Method)

//This would compile
typeof(IGenericInterface<>)
```

I think this should be valid `c#-6.0` or am I missing something or is there a better way to do this. I don't want to use a string for the Method name as if the method is renamed code would break without any build-time errors.

Comment: if `nameof(IGenericInterface<>)` works then try `$"{nameof(IGenericInterface<>)}.{nameof(Method)}"`

Comment: this would not produce the same output as nameof(IGenericInterface<>.Method) should return Method

Comment: [for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878137/nameof-with-generics)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is expected. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx), your expression is disallowed, because it refers to an unbound generic type:

> Because the argument needs to be an expression syntactically, there are many things disallowed that are not useful to list. The following are worth mentioning that produce errors: predefined types (for example, `int` or `void`), nullable types (`Point?`), array types (`Customer[,]`), pointer types (`Buffer*`), qualified alias (`A::B`), and unbound generic types (`Dictionary<,>`), preprocessing symbols (`DEBUG`), and labels (`loop:`).

You can work around this limitation by supplying a generic parameter:

```
nameof(IGenericInterface<object>.Method)
```

**Note:** I think Microsoft should tweak `nameof` feature to allow references to methods of unbound generic types.

Comment: Is strange this is expected, and yes i agree they should allow how would one go about raising that to them.

Comment: Under the hood, generics are basically expanded to all the types they are used with, right? This is probably a rather minor concern, but using `nameof(IGenericInterface<object>)` in code will then generate the interface `IGenericInterface<object>` which might not otherwise be needed anywhere. It would definitely make more sense if `nameof()` would support unbound generics.

Comment: FYI: `object` won't work depending on any constraints on that generic parameter

Comment: Just be aware that passing anything to it, will force the compiler to generate a real class with an object type, so be aware of this drawback

Answer (score 5):

Just use a sample type in order to compile.

```
string name = nameof(IGenericInterface<int>.Method) // will be Method
```