# Why is this expression working? (C# 6.0)

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, nameof

`nameof(ServiceResult<object>.Result)`, where  `ServiceResult<object>` is my custom type and `Result` is the field of this type. `ServiceResult<object>` is just a declaration of type, it doesn't have operator new and (), but official page of MS says `nameof` accepts variable and its members. **Why** this expression works? I didn't see such declarations before.

Comment: You will found your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878137/nameof-with-generics

Comment: `nameof` returns the name of the symbol at compile time. In this case the symbol is `Result`. It doesn't *create* an instance of whatever the symbol's type is nor check its values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spec you mentioned is probably an old one, C# 6.0 `nameof` operator reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof

> The argument to `nameof` must be a simple name, qualified name, member access, base access with a specified member, or this access with a specified member. The argument expression identifies a code definition, but it is never evaluated.

In your case, it's an expression. Similar to

`nameof(C.Method2) -> "Method2"`

from the examples list in that article.

**Examples**

```
using Stuff = Some.Cool.Functionality  
class C {  
    static int Method1 (string x, int y) {}  
    static int Method1 (string x, string y) {}  
    int Method2 (int z) {}  
    string f<T>() => nameof(T);  
}  

var c = new C()  

nameof(C) -> "C"  
nameof(C.Method1) -> "Method1"   
nameof(C.Method2) -> "Method2"  
nameof(c.Method1) -> "Method1"   
nameof(c.Method2) -> "Method2"  
nameof(z) -> "z" // inside of Method2 ok, inside Method1 is a compiler error  
nameof(Stuff) = "Stuff"  
nameof(T) -> "T" // works inside of method but not in attributes on the method  
nameof(f) -> "f"  
nameof(f<T>) -> syntax error  
nameof(f<>) -> syntax error  
nameof(Method2()) -> error "This expression does not have a name"
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. That explains everything. Thank you.